Create an index at oracle sql server on tablespace
I want to create an index of type context on a tablespace different from the one the table is. Also I want to pass parameters.
The data type of ATTACH_BIN is BLOB.
CREATE INDEX ATT_INDEX 
    ON ATTACH(ATTACH_BIN) 
    INDEXTYPE IS CTXSYS.CONTEXT 
    PARAMETERS 
('DATASTORE CTXSYS.DEFAULT_DATASTORE SYNC(EVERY trunc(sysdate + 1))') 
TABLESPACE IDX;

ORA-29855: error occurred in the execution of ODCIINDEXCREATE routine
ORA-20000: Oracle Text error:
DRG-11000: invalid keyword (
ORA-06512: at "CTXSYS.DRUE", line 186
ORA-06512: at "CTXSYS.TEXTINDEXMETHODS", line 320 00000 - "error occurred in the execution of ODCIINDEXCREATE routine" *Cause: Failed to successfully execute the ODCIIndexCreate routine.
